# Reset jQuery one() so that it will fire again

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery `one()` method on an event handler to fire once then de-register itself. Something like:

```
$(".main").one('mousedown', '.resizeBar', function (e) { /* my code */ });
```

Then some ajax (actually, a .net postback) resets most of the page (without reloading) and I want to set up the event handler again. Is there a way to either re-set the `one()` event handler to be active again? Manually re-triggering it this way doesn't work, obviously:

```
$(".main .resizeBar").trigger("mousedown");
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

just wrap that code in a function

```
function mainMouseDownOne() {
    $(".main").one('mousedown', '.resizeBar', function (e) { /* my code */ });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    mainMouseDownOne();

    .ajax({
        ...
        success: function() {
            ...
            mainMouseDownOne();
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend wrapping the one() method bind inside a function call, then you can call the function (to bind the initial event handlers) on page load, and again on success of the Ajax call.

```
var bindEvents = function(){
  $(".main").one('mousedown', '.resizeBar', function (e) { /* my code */ });
};

$(function(){ bindEvents(); }); // call the one() method on page load.

$.post(pageURL, function(data){
  bindEvents(); // As an example, after some sort of Ajax or post-reset event.
});
```

Comment: Apparently, someone posted a very similar (same) response right before I got to submit mine. Sorry for the redundancy.

Comment: No worries. I'll accept his as it was first, but I appreciate your answer. I'm confused about why you put $(function(){bindEvents();}); instead of just bindEvents(); though.

Comment: It was so that, on page load, you wait for the DOM to be ready before calling the initial bindEvents() function... definitely want the page (HTML) loaded before binding the event.

Comment: $(function(){}); is short-hand for $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know that shorthand. Thanks.