# how to reset .one() without refreshing page

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh, partial-page-refresh

i have a submit button that i attached a `.one()` mouse event to, cos otherwise if you accidentally double click it will send the information twice.

the only problem is that once the information is sent, i refresh the containing `div` (i don't what the whole page to refresh) which then displays the new information. But if you go to add more information it won't allow you to click the submit button again as its already been clicked.

i thought as im refreshing the `div` that it would reset....but it doesnt. how do i fix this?

thanx

**edit**

so with the help of JOE ive done this. but it still fires twice on double click. have i done this right?

```
    var clickActive = false;
$("body").on("click", '.post_comment_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(clickActive) return;
        else { 
        clickActive = true;
        var post = $(this).parents('.update_comment').parents('#post_comment');
        var anchor = $(post).siblings('.comment_list').find('ul:first');
        var comment = $(this).parents('.update_comment').children('textarea.post_comment').val();
        var user = $(this).parents('.update_comment').children('input.user').val();
        var msg_id = $(this).parents('.update_comment').children('input.message_id').val();
            if (comment == '')  loadComments();     
            else {
                $.post('messages.php', { 
                    comment: comment, 
                    message_id: msg_id, 
                    post_comment: 'true' }, function(data) {
                    //create new comment//  
                        $('body').append(data);
                        var newcomment = "<li><div class='comment_container'><div class='date'>less than 1 minute ago</div><div class='name'>" + user + " </div><div class='info_bar'><div class='edit_comment'><a href='#' class='comment_edit'>Edit</a></div><span>|</span><a href='#' class='delete_comment'>Delete</a></div><div class='fadeOut_comment'><div class='posted_comment'> " + nl2br(htmlEntities(comment.trim())) + " </div></div></li>";
                        $(post).slideUp(400);
                        $(newcomment).fadeIn(500, function() {
                            loadComments();
                        }).appendTo(anchor);
                        clickActive = false;
                });
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800611/reset-jquery-one-so-that-it-will-fire-again The one event will work again if you put it inside a function.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800611/reset-jquery-one-so-that-it-will-fire-again

Comment: you shouldn't be using `one()`, but `on()`, and then `off()` to disable the button until the content is updated.

Comment: i read that question, thanx. i put it inside a function...but it still downt work, how do i call the function after its been used once?

Comment: same problem with `off()` tho. how do i get it to allow me to fir it again?

Comment: @joe, yes it is a dupe....but the other question didnt work for me.... so i had to ask another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to disable the button so that the user can't click it twice in a row.
Adapt the following logic to your code.

```
//Bind a click event handler to your button
$("body").on("click", "you_button_selector", function(e)
{
    //Prevent any default behaviour, we're dealing with this ourselves
    e.preventDefault();
    //First, disable the button
    $("your_button_selector").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    //Then, make your ajax call
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "http://example.com",
        success: function(data)
        {
            //When your ajax call returns, enable the button again
            $("your_button_selector").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: genius! totally worked. i didnt even need to enable the button again as i reloaded the `div`. thanx dude....or dudette