# how to re-enable JQuery .one click handler

Tags: jquery

I have a comments box, that checks if the user has entered any details

```
if(comments < 1)
{
  alert("enter a comment");
}
```

And the function is triggered by

```
  $('#btnSave').one("click", function(e){};
```

How can I re-enable the button's .one click if the user hasn't entered any text?

Comment: the `.one` jquery method, will register the event handler to fire only  1 times. If that is not what you want, use `.on` instead of `.one`

Comment: you could put a check in your function to see if the textbox is empty and then do $('#btnSave').one("click", function(e){}; again...  I'm not sure how I feel about the particular approach but it would probably behave as you are expecting without a major rewrite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can wrap your .one function inside another function .

```
var saveBtnClick = function(){
   $('#btnSave').one("click", function(e){};
};
```

you can read this question for implementations :

[Reset jQuery one() so that it will fire again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800611/reset-jquery-one-so-that-it-will-fire-again)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<form>
<textarea name="comment" required></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Note: Internet explorer not support this

or

```
jQuery('#btnSave').on("submit", function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     if(jQuery('#field').val().length < 1){ 
         alert('enter a comment');
     }
)};
```