# Prevent multiple upload Ajax PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Currently experiencing issues with multiple uploads on AJAX.

I've tried:

```
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

In my function but it keeps duplicating anyways. Basically you can spam the submit button and multiple uploads will happen.
Any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/* Data Insert Starts Here */
$(document).on('submit', '#SavePost', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    /* Image upload Ajax */
    $.ajax({
        url: "create.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function () {

            $("#err").fadeOut();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'invalid file') {
                // invalid file format.
                $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
            } else {
                 $("#dis").fadeOut();
            $("#dis").fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $("#dis").html('<div class="alert alert-info">' + data + '</div>');
                // view uploaded file.
                $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();
                $("#SavePost")[0].reset();
                $("body").fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    $("body").fadeOut('slow');
                    window.location.href = "memberpage.php";
                 });
            });
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            $("#err").html(e).fadeIn();
        }
    });
    /* Image upload Ajax ENDING */
    return false;
});
/* Data Insert Ends Here */
```

Comment: try using `.one` instead of `.on`

Comment: Been on it ever since last night and that saved me a lot of time. Post it and I'll mark it as solved. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.one` instead of `.on`

It ensures that it will only fire one time.

If you still want to submit it multiple time refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11800662/559079).